# Automatically mount and repeatedly check for Drobo mount

Tags: mount, drobo

Is there a way I can repeatedly check for a Drobo mount and if it's not there perform a mount? I have a Drobo which I use from a few Macs and throughout the day at different points mounts seem to kick off and it causes issues with users.